# my programm is not adding data to my json file and i do not know why

Tags: javascript, html, json

if the "+" button is clicked a new view pops up where you are able to write data and that data should be saved/ submited ("hinzufügen ")to be added to the data.json file. The Problem i'm having is that the data is not beeing added to the file and i do not understand why that is. i don't get any error or something like that. i think there is a problem with how i try to call the file , like it is not properly finding it :/

My next problem would be how to edit an existing data. so if you click on one person i would like to have the option to edit the data of that person

```
this.person = [];

fetch('data.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => createListContact(data));


/**
* Function to display as a list data.json
*/
function createListContact(data) {

    document.querySelector('main.view').innerHTML ="";

  const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
  h1.innerHTML ="Listenansicht";

  const ol = document.createElement('ol');
  ol.classList.add("list-view");
  ol.addEventListener("click", showDetails);
  ol.appendChild(h1);

  data.personen.forEach((person, i) => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.classList.add("button");
    li.setAttribute("id", `person_${i}`);
    li.innerHTML = person.nachname + ', ' + person.vorname;
    li.personData = person;

    ol.append(li);
  });
  document.querySelector('main.view').append(ol);

  // Options 
  document.querySelector('nav.options').innerHTML="";

  const add = document.createElement('img');
  add.setAttribute("src","glyphicons-433-plus.png");
  add.addEventListener("click", addPerson);
  document.querySelector('nav.options').append(add);
}

/** 
 *  Function to open detailed info
 *
 */
function showDetails(e) {
  const view = document.getElementsByClassName("view")[0];
  view.style.opacity = 1;

  if (e.target.nodeName == 'LI') {
    var details = document.createElement('div');
    details.className = 'details';
    details.id = "test";
    view.style.opacity = 0;

    var close = document.createElement('div');
    close.className = 'details-close';
    close.innerHTML = 'zurück';
    close.addEventListener('click', e => {
      details.parentNode.removeChild(details);
      view.style.opacity =1;
    });

    // title
          const title = document.createElement('div');
          title.classList.add("details-title");
            const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
            h1.innerHTML="Detailansicht";
            title.appendChild(h1);

    var info = document.createElement('div');
    info.classList.add("details-content");
  
      const name = document.createElement('p');
      name.innerHTML ='Name: '+ e.target.personData.nachname + ', ' +e.target.personData.vorname;
      const tel = document.createElement('p');
      tel.innerHTML = 'Tel: '+ e.target.personData.telefonnummer;
      const mail = document.createElement('p');
      mail.innerHTML = 'E-mail: '+ e.target.personData.email;
   
    info.append(name,tel,mail);
    

    details.append(title, info);
    details.append(close);
    document.body.append(details);
  }

}
/*
* Function to add one person
*/
function addPerson(e) {
  const view = document.getElementsByClassName("view")[0];
  view.style.opacity = 1;

  if (e.target.nodeName == 'IMG') {
    var add = document.createElement('div');
    add.className = "details";
    view.style.opacity = 0;

  // close button
  var close = document.createElement('div');
    close.className = 'details-close';
    close.innerHTML = 'Zurück';
    close.addEventListener('click', e => {
      add.parentNode.removeChild(add);
      view.style.opacity =1;
    });

  // submit button
  var submit = document.createElement('input');
  submit.classList = 'details-sub';
  submit.setAttribute("value","Hinzufügen");
  submit.setAttribute("type","submit");
  
  // title
  const title = document.createElement('div');
          title.classList.add("details-title");
            const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
            h1.innerHTML="Bearbeitungsansicht";
            title.appendChild(h1);
 

  var info = document.createElement('form');
    info.classList.add("details-content");
    info.setAttribute("method","post");

    //vorname
      const vname = document.createElement('p');
      const vl = document.createElement('lable');
        vl.innerHTML = "Vorname";
        const vi = document.createElement('input');
        vi.setAttribute("name","vorname");
        vi.setAttribute("type","text");
        vi.setAttribute("placeholder","Texteingabe");
        vi.setAttribute("required", "true");
        //vi.setAttribute("value","$vname");
        vl.append(vi);
      vname.append(vl);
      
    //nachname
      const nname = document.createElement('p');
      const nl = document.createElement('lable');
        nl.innerHTML = "Nachname";
        const ni = document.createElement('input');
        ni.setAttribute("name","nachname");
        ni.setAttribute("type","text");
        ni.setAttribute("placeholder","Texteingabe");
        ni.setAttribute("required", "true");
        //ni.setAttribute("value","$nname");
        nl.append(ni);
      nname.append(nl);

    //telefonnummer
      const tel = document.createElement('p');
      const tl = document.createElement('lable');
        tl.innerHTML = "Telefonnummer";
        const ti = document.createElement('input');
        ti.setAttribute("name","telefonnummer");
        ti.setAttribute("type","tel");
        ti.setAttribute("placeholder","Eingabe v. Ortsvorwahl und Anschluss");
        ti.setAttribute("required", "true");
        //ti.setAttribute("value","$tnr");
        tl.append(ti);
      tel.append(tl);

    // mail
      const mail = document.createElement('p');
      const ml = document.createElement('lable');
        ml.innerHTML = "E-mail";
        const mi = document.createElement('input');
        mi.setAttribute("name","email");
        mi.setAttribute("type","email");
        mi.setAttribute("placeholder","Eingabe einer E-Mailadresse");
        mi.setAttribute("required", "true");
        //mi.setAttribute("value","$email");
        ml.append(mi);
      mail.append(ml);
   
    info.append(vname, nname, tel, mail,submit);
    

    add.append(title, info);
    add.append(close);
    document.body.append(add);
}
}
/*
* Function to remove one person
*/
function removePerson(li){
    
}
```

```
html{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  background-color: #886b6b77;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  font-size: 70%;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;

  @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    font-size: 100%;
  }
}
header {

}


ol h1 {
  color: #886b6b77;
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  color: black;
}
/*
* list-view 
*/
/* ul and li */
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
}
/* button */
.list-view .button {
    appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3em;
  padding: 0 1em;

}

.list-view .button:hover{
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}
/* details */
.details {
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(black, 0.2);
  left: 50%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 70em;
  text-align: left;
  max-height: 130vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

 /* close */
}
.details-close{
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    height: 4.5em;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    color: black;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 4.5em;
}
.details-sub{
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    height: 4.5em;
    font-size: 16px;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    color: black;
    right: 70;
    top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border:0;
}
.details-title {
    color: #886b6b77;
    padding: 1.5em 2em;
    pointer-events: all;
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% - 4.5em);

   h1 {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
      font-weight: 600;
      line-height: normal;
  }
}

/* content */
.details-content {
    border-top: 1px solid #886b6b77;
    padding: 2em;
    pointer-events: all;
    overflow: auto;
  }

/* overlay */
.details-overlay {
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: rgba(#0f172a, 0.8);
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;

  details[open] & {
    pointer-events: all;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}
nav {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
        if(file_exists('data.json')){
            $current_data = file_get_contents('data.json');
            $array_data = json_decode($current_data, true);
            $extra = array(
                'vorname'       => $_POST['vorname'],
                'nachname'      => $_POST['nachname'],
                'telefonnummer'         => $_POST['telefonnummer'],
                'email'     => $_POST['email']
                );
                $array_data[] = $extra;
                $final_data = json_encode($array_data);
                    
        }
        
    }
?>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="skript.js"></script>
    <title>Main</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header></header>
    <main class="view"></main>
    <nav class="options"></nav>     
</body>

</html>
```

```
{
  "personen": [
    {
      "vorname": "Max",
      "nachname": "Mustermann",
      "telefonnummer": "555-555-1234",
      "email": "max.mustermann@example.com"
    },
    {
      "vorname": "Lisa",
      "nachname": "Müller",
      "telefonnummer": "555-555-5678",
      "email": "lisa.mueller@example.com"
    
    },
    {
      "vorname": "Peter",
      "nachname": "Schmidt",
      "telefonnummer": "555-555-6785",
      "email": "peter.schmidt@example.com"
    },
    {
      "vorname": "Hans",
      "nachname": "Müller",
      "telefonnummer": "555-555-1548",
      "email": "hans.mueller@example.com"
    },
    {
      "vorname": "Karl",
      "nachname": "Müller",
      "telefonnummer": "555-555-5847",
      "email": "karl.mueller@example.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: In your PHP it looks like you are reading the JSON file into an array and appending data, but you never write the updated data out to the file. Try `file_put_contents("data.json", $final_data);` at the end of the inner `if` statement.

Comment: saddly that did not fix it